# Where is the file added by Hive?

Tags: hive

I use the command 'add file ' and the file will be load by a UDF subsequently.

But I cannot find the file added by hive at HDFS(hdfs://namenode:8026/user/hdfs) and I need the path in my udf method.

What is the path of the file and how to use it via udf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dfs path is not accessible from UDF/UDTF, you need to provide local path in UDF/UDTF.

My approach:

Check if the file is present in locally at '/tmp' or not. 
If yes and has non-zero file length then use it, else Pull the file from DFS:/shared to '/tmp and proceed.

```
public static boolean readFile(){   
    BufferedReader br=null;
    try {
        File f = new File("/tmp/" + fileName);
        if (! f.exists() || f.length() == 0){
            // Pull fresh file from dfs:/xyz.
            String cmd = "hadoop fs -get /xyz/" + fileName + " /tmp/";
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            System.err.println("Pulling Mapping file from HDFS. Running: " + cmd);
            Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
            try {
                // Waiting for the job to complete.
                pr.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //open file for reading
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/" + fileName));

        String line= br.readLine();

        while(line != null){
            System.out.println(line);               
            //read next line
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        br.close();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){

        System.err.println("File not found - "+fileName);
        return false;

    }catch(IOException e){

        System.err.println("Error while reading from the preset file");         
        return false;           
    }

    return true;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`add file` add files in distributed cache in Hive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I have to find a new way

Comment: I will help you, if you provide detail requirement. I already worked on this scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I'm writing an UDTF to resolve IP address via a *.dat file bought from a company. So I need to indicate the .dat file path in my UDTF method. I have put the file on the dfs but when I run the method it always says: 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/192.168.7.20:8020/tmp/ip_20170204.dat (No such file or directory)'

Comment: By the way, the detail of my UDTF Java code can be seen in my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799688/udfjava-permission-denied-at-hdfs